# Set event for each level zoom google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How do I specify load one kml file when I zoom each level google map?
This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Getting Properties With Event Handlers</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        var kmlLayer;
        function initMap() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 8,
                center: { lat: 10.89779, lng: 106.64619 }
            });

            map.addListener('idle', function () {
                if (map.getZoom() == 9) {
                    //alert('aa');
                    kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
                        url: 'a.kml',
                        map: map
                    });
                }
                else if (map.getZoom() == 10) {
                     kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
                        url: 'b.kml',
                        map: map
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API&callback=initMap">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

It means when `map.getZoom() == 9`, The map will draw by file `a.kml`. `Map.getZoom() == 10` will draw by `b.kml` file and all detail created by `a.kml` file will be removed.

But my code above doesn't smooth when zoom and detail is created by `a.kml` file. It is not removed when `Map.getZoom() == 10`.

Please help me fix this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hide the existing KmlLayer before displaying the new one.  Something like:

```
var kmlLayer;
map.addListener('idle', function () {
    if (map.getZoom() == 9) {
        if (kmlLayer && kmlLayer.setMap) kmlLayer.setMap(null);
        kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            url: 'a.kml',
            map: map
        });
    }
    else if (map.getZoom() == 10) {
         if (kmlLayer && kmlLayer.setMap) kmlLayer.setMap(null);
         kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            url: 'b.kml',
            map: map
         });
    }
```

(if you have KmlLayers defined for all the zoom levels, you may want to move the code that hides the existing layer outside of the `if`)

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4qrek68b/1/)